# How to use document.querySelectorAll() in `ng-include`angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I used `document.querySelectorAll()`to select my class in view.
I got problems when my class was included from another file.

How to use `document.querySelectorAll()` if I import my file using `ng-include`?

Comment: Can you update your question code. And explain the scenario where you used  `document.querySelectorAll()` in the both the files.

Comment: probably using it in wrong part of app and chances are you don't even need to use it. Provide sample code

Comment: I got the answer...I need to put in my included file with `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` and it is working. Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer...I need to put in my included file with `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` and it is working.

Thanks for any comments.